# Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex when using DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following partial query

```
var finalResults =

    (from o in outerJoin
    orderby o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num, o.timeKey.timeKey.Month, o.Key.Key.PlantId, o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId
    select new
    {
        IndicatorName = IndicatorName,
        LocationName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PlantId,
        GroupingName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId,
        Year = o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num,
        Month = o.timeKey.timeKey.Month, 
        Numerator = o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours != null ? o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0 : 0,
        Denominator = o.timeKey.timeKey.Hours - o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0,
        Weight = o.timeKey.timeKey.NetMaximumCapacity,                         
    }).ToList();
```

The query works fine except that Month gives me a month and year in the format:

```
August 2012
```

and I need it in this format:

```
08
```

I changed my code as reflected below:

```
var finalResults =

    (from o in outerJoin
    orderby o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num, o.timeKey.timeKey.Month, o.Key.Key.PlantId, o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId
    select new
    {
        IndicatorName = IndicatorName,
        LocationName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PlantId,
        GroupingName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId,
        Year = o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num,
        Month = DateTime.ParseExact(o.timeKey.timeKey.Month.Split(' ')[0], "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month,
        Numerator = o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours != null ? o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0 : 0,
        Denominator = o.timeKey.timeKey.Hours - o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0,
        Weight = o.timeKey.timeKey.NetMaximumCapacity,                         
    }).ToList();
```

but now I receive the following error:

```
Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?  Changing the format in the DB is not an option.

Here is the entire query:

```
protected IList<DataResults> QueryData(HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC ranges)
{
    using (var context = new DataClassesDataContext(_connectionString))
    {
        context.CommandTimeout = 240;                
        const string IndicatorName = "{DFD88372-FB87-49AC-8576-68DCBE7B00E8}";

        List<string> typeCodes = new List<string>() { "D1", "D2", "D3", "DP", "PD", "DM", "D4" };
        DataResults endItem = new DataResults();
        List<DataResults> ListOfResults = new List<DataResults>();

        var results =

            (from v in context.vDimUnits
             join vf in context.vFactEnergyAllocations on v.UnitKey equals vf.UnitKey
             join vd in context.vDimGadsEvents on vf.GadsEventKey equals vd.GadsEventKey
             join vt in context.vDimTimes on vf.TimeKey equals vt.TimeKey
             where typeCodes.Contains(vd.GadsEventTypeCode) 
                && vt.Year_Num >= ranges.StartTimeUTC.Year 
                && vt.Year_Num <= ranges.EndTimeUTC.Year                        
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "N/A"
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "UNK"
                && v.PlantId != "UNK" 
                && v.NercUnitType != "WT"
             group vf by new { v.PlantId, v.PhysicalUnitId, v.NetDependableCapacity, vt.Year_Num, vt.Month } into groupItem
             select new
             {
                 groupItem.Key.Year_Num,
                 groupItem.Key.Month,
                 groupItem.Key.PhysicalUnitId,
                 groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity,
                 Derate_Hours = groupItem.Sum(x => (float?)x.AllocatedEnergyMwh / groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity),
                 groupItem.Key.PlantId,
                 Unit = groupItem.Count()
             });

        var resultHours =

            (from f in
            (from vt in context.vDimTimes
            from v in context.vDimUnits
            where vt.Year_Num >= ranges.StartTimeUTC.Year
                && vt.Year_Num <= ranges.EndTimeUTC.Year 
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "N/A" 
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "UNK" 
                && v.PlantId != "UNK" 
                && v.NercUnitType != "WT"
            select new { v.PlantId, v.PhysicalUnitId, vt.Year_Num, vt.Month, vt.TimeKey, v.NetMaximumCapacity }).Distinct()
             group f by new { f.PhysicalUnitId, f.Year_Num, f.Month, f.PlantId } into groupItem
            select new
            {
                 groupItem.Key.PhysicalUnitId,
                 groupItem.Key.Year_Num,
                 groupItem.Key.Month,
                 groupItem.Key.PlantId,
                 groupItem.First().NetMaximumCapacity,
                 Hours = groupItem.Count()
            });

        var serviceHrsResults =

            (from v in context.vDimUnits
             join vf in context.vFactEnergyAllocations on v.UnitKey equals vf.UnitKey
             join vt in context.vDimTimes on vf.TimeKey equals vt.TimeKey
             join vus in context.vDimUnitStates on vf.UnitStateKey equals vus.UnitStateKey

             where vus.UnitStateType != "Active" 
                && vt.Year_Num >= ranges.StartTimeUTC.Year 
                && vt.Year_Num <= ranges.EndTimeUTC.Year
                && v.NetDependableCapacity != 0 
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "N/A" 
                && v.PhysicalUnitId != "UNK" 
                && v.PlantId != "UNK" 
                && v.NercUnitType != "WT"

             group vf by new { v.PlantId, vt.Year_Num, vt.Month, v.PhysicalUnitId, v.NetDependableCapacity } into groupItem

             select new
             {
                 groupItem.Key.Year_Num,
                 groupItem.Key.Month,
                 groupItem.Key.PhysicalUnitId,
                 groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity,
                 groupItem.Key.PlantId,
                 Unit = groupItem.Count()
             });

        var outerJoin1 =

            (from h in resultHours
             join u in results on new { h.PhysicalUnitId, h.Year_Num, h.Month } equals new { u.PhysicalUnitId, u.Year_Num, u.Month } into outer
             from grouping in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { timeKey = h, Key = grouping });

        var outerJoin2 =

            (from h in resultHours
             join s in serviceHrsResults on new { h.PhysicalUnitId, h.Year_Num, h.Month } equals new { s.PhysicalUnitId, s.Year_Num, s.Month } into outer2
             from grouping in outer2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { timeKey = h, Key = grouping });

        var outerJoin =

            (from a in outerJoin1
             join b in outerJoin2 on new { a.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId, a.timeKey.Year_Num, a.timeKey.Month } equals new
             {
                 b.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId,
                 b.timeKey.Year_Num,
                 b.timeKey.Month
             } into outer
             from grouping in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { timeKey = a, Key = grouping }).Distinct();


        var finalResults =

            (from o in outerJoin
             orderby o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num, o.timeKey.timeKey.Month, o.Key.Key.PlantId, o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId
             select new
             {
                IndicatorName = IndicatorName,
                 LocationName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PlantId,
                 GroupingName = o.timeKey.timeKey.PhysicalUnitId,
                 Year = o.timeKey.timeKey.Year_Num,
                 Month = DateTime.ParseExact(o.timeKey.timeKey.Month.Split(' ')[0], "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month,
                 Numerator = o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours != null ? o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0 : 0,
                 Denominator = o.timeKey.timeKey.Hours - o.timeKey.Key.Derate_Hours ?? 0,
                 Weight = o.timeKey.timeKey.NetMaximumCapacity,                         
                 }).ToList();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < finalResults.Count; counter++)
        {
            var item = finalResults[counter];
            endItem = new DataResults();
            ListOfResults.Add(endItem);
            endItem.IndicatorName = IndicatorName;
            endItem.LocationName = item.LocationName;
            endItem.GroupingName = item.GroupingName;
            endItem.Year = item.Year;
            endItem.Month = item.Month.ToString();
            endItem.Numerator = item.Numerator;
            endItem.Denominator = item.Denominator;
            endItem.Weight = item.Weight.Value;                    
        }
        return ListOfResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does type has the timekey property in that case?

Comment: What is `o.timeKey.timeKey`? We have no idea what data you're dealing with. (Also, it would really help readability if you could evaluate `o.timeKey.timeKey` once, instead of *18 times* in your query.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll post the entire query.  I didn't because it's long as nasty.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: No need to post the entire query - but a short and *complete* example with all the relevant information would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We still don't really have much context, but I'll guess at an appropriate answer anyway :)

If you're trying to do a lot of work within a query expression which is being translated to SQL, you may find it's better to split the query into two parts:

- The part done in SQL, with as much filtering as possible and only specifying the data you need, but in a "raw" format
- A part done in LINQ to Objects, which can use any .NET methods you need.

You use `AsEnumerable` to effectively flip from using the methods in `Queryable` to the ones in `Enumerable`. So you might have:

```
var sqlQuery = from ...
               orderby ...
               select ...;

var finalQuery = sqlQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(entry => new { 
                     // Call whatever methods you like in here
                 });
```

This avoids having to ask the LINQ provider to generate SQL to emulate things like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(o.timeKey.timeKey.Month.Split(' ')[0], "MMMM", 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month,
```

It also means that you can write helper methods which are easily tested outside your query:

```
var finalQuery = sqlQuery.AsEnumerable().Select(entry => new { 
                     Month = ConvertYearMonthToMonthNumber(entry.Month),
                     ...
                 });
```

Note that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` may very well be the *wrong* culture here, unless you really know that the data stored in your database is in the same culture as your user, which may not be the invariant culture. I think it's much more likely that you really want to use the invariant culture... or just use `Calendar.MonthNames.IndexOf(month)`.